# Explicit flattening of multiple arrays in a JSON file using Standard SQL syntax in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I am trying to flatten multiple (adjacent and nested) arrays in a JSON file in BigQuery using Standard SQL syntax. Essentially, I am trying to convert this nested structure:

`{
    "kind": "person",
    "fullName": "John Doe",
    "age": 22,
    "gender": "Male",
    "phoneNumber": {
        "areaCode": "206",
        "number": "1234567"
    },
    "children": [{
        "name": "Jane",
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": "6"
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "gender": "Male",
        "age": "15"
    }],
    "citiesLived": [{
        "place": "Seattle",
        "yearsLived": ["1995", "1996"]
    }, {
        "place": "Stockholm",
        "yearsLived": ["2005"]
    }]
}`

into:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Full Name</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Age</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Gender</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">PhoneNumber.Area Code</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">PhoneNumber.Number</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Children.Name</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Children.Gender</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Children.Age</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">CitiesLived.Place</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">CitiesLived.YearsLived</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Jane</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Female</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Seattle</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1995</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">15</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Seattle</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1995</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Jane</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Female</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Seattle</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1996</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Jane</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Female</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">6</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Stockholm</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2005</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">15</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Seattle</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1996</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John Doe</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">22</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">206</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">1234567</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">John</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Male</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">15</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">Stockholm</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2005</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I used CROSS JOIN with UNNEST but I am stuck in the nested arrays part (YearsLived array within CitiesLived). How do I flatten this correctly?

Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Comment: not clear what you need! try to present better schema of your table and what exactly output you expect. if (as you mentioned) you tried some thing  - present the code and show what is not as you expected. All this will help us to help you! otherwise I see very low chances for this question to be answered. You should read more about [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please also see if the [Working with Arrays](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) topic is useful. The are some examples that demonstrate the cross join with UNNEST pattern.